# Is it possibile to enter dates from a drop-down calendar?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

In Excel 2003, is it possible to enter dates in a cell from a drop-down calendar instead of entering them manually?

Comment: What did your research tell you? A search for "excel 2003 drop down calendar" gives [Adding a calendar drop down box to Excel 2003](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/adding-a-calendar-drop-down-box-to-excel-2003/3bb460b6-c966-471a-ace3-49c1a9343b14) as the first link.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you Yass very much, your link answered my question.

Comment: Answer added...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is it possible to enter dates in a cell from a drop-down calendar?

Use the following for Excel 2003.

---

#### Adding a calendar drop down box to Excel 2003

> 1. Insert > Object, scroll down and click on "Microsoft Calendar Control".
> 2. Right click the worksheet tab and view code.
> 3. Paste the following code:
>
>    ```
>    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
>        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
>        'Change this to your range of dates
>        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then
>            Calendar1.Top = Target.Top + Target.Height
>            Calendar1.Left = Target.Left + Target.Width / 2 - Calendar1.Width / 2
>            Calendar1.Visible = True
>            Calendar1.Value = Now
>        ElseIf Calendar1.Visible Then Calendar1.Visible = False
>        End If
>    End Sub
>    Private Sub Calendar1_Click()
>        ActiveCell.Value = (Calendar1.Value)
>        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "dd mmm yy"
>    End Sub
>    ```
>
>    Note in the code the range for the dates is set as A1:A100, maintain
>      the syntax and change this to suit.
> 4. Close VB editor.
> 5. Exit design mode.
>
> When you click in a1:A100 you get a calendar that defaults to today's
>   date.
>
> Click a date and it gets entered in the active cell.

Source [Adding a calendar drop down box to Excel 2003](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/adding-a-calendar-drop-down-box-to-excel-2003/3bb460b6-c966-471a-ace3-49c1a9343b14)

Answer (score 2):

There is [number of ways](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel%20addin%20dropdown%20calendar):

- [adding form field with dropdown calendar](http://www.fontstuff.com/excel/exltut03.htm) can be more comfortable, but suitable for limited cell count made manually.

  1. enable *Developer* tab in Excel
  2. select Insert > others (bottom-right icon) > Microsoft Date and Time Picker Control 6.0
  3. place the control on your sheet
  4. using *Developer* tab, display property sheet of the control
  5. set *LinkedCell* property to your cell
  6. using *Developer* tab, switch off *Design Mode*
- [adding universal date/time dropdown picker](https://xltools.net/excel-popup-calendar/) can be slightly less intuitive to use, but you do not need any further special handling of date cells

  - you can either get that addin (well, for [excel-2003](/questions/tagged/excel-2003) you need to find something like that) or create your own with similar functionality (needs experience with software development). The way goes through Excel add-ins.

Comment: Thank you miroxlav. Unfortunately, Excel 2003 neither has a Developer tab nor it supports universal picker. But the link in the comment of Yass answered my question.